# SWING Application with ServerSocket

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I am trying to build a swing frame that is invoked and runs the Server using socket .I have tried to make the server run on a separate thread as shown ,

Interface.java

```
public class Interface implements ActionListener{

User user;

JFrame frame;
JScrollPane scroll;
JTextArea text;
JButton b1,b2,b3,b4;

ServerSocket ss;
Socket socket;
int port;
ObjectInputStream in;
ObjectOutputStream out;
Packet packet;

public Interface(User u) 
{       
    user=u;

    port = DataBase1.getPortNumberOfUser(user.getUserName());

    frame=new JFrame(user.getUserName()+" - "+user.getEmail());

    text=new JTextArea("                        Welcome "+user.getName());

    scroll = new JScrollPane(text);

    b1=new JButton("UpLoad");
    b2=new JButton("GenerateKey");
    b3=new JButton("ShareKey");
    b4=new JButton("Exit");

    frame.setSize(500,400);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    text.setBounds(5,5,250,350);

    scroll.setBounds(5,5,250,350);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    b1.setBounds(275,50,200,50);
    b1.setActionCommand("upload");
    b1.addActionListener(this);

    b2.setBounds(275,125,200,50);
    b2.setActionCommand("generateKey");
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    b3.setBounds(275,200,200,50);

    b4.setBounds(275,275,200,50);
    b4.setActionCommand("exit");
    b4.addActionListener(this);


    frame.add(scroll);
    frame.add(b1);
    frame.add(b2);
    frame.add(b3);
    frame.add(b4);

    try {

        ss= new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Socket Created !");
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for Multi client ..");
            socket = ss.accept();
            System.out.println("here");
            new MultiClientServerThread(socket,text).start();
        }


    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            ss.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

MultiClientServerThread.java

```
public class MultiClientServerThread extends Thread {

protected Socket socket;
private ObjectInputStream in;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private Packet packet;
private JTextArea display;

public MultiClientServerThread(Socket socket ,JTextArea display) {
    in=null;
    out=null;
    packet=null;
    this.socket=socket;
    this.display=display;
}

public void logIn()
{
    display.append("\n\n"+packet.getType()+"  :  "+packet.getContents());
}

public void signUp()
{
    display.append("\n\n"+packet.getType()+"  :  "+packet.getContents());
}

public void run() {
    try {

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        packet = (Packet)in.readObject();
        System.out.println("\n\nType :  "+ packet.getType()+"\nKey : "+packet.getKey()+"\nContents : "+packet.getContents());
        if((packet.getType()).equals("LOGIN"))
            logIn();
        else if((packet.getType()).equals("SIGNUP"))
            signUp();
        out.writeObject("Received Your message client");        

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
            return;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

but the swing GUI is not loading ,that is ,I am not able to view the contents of the frame ., Can anyone please help ,Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I do let know, that while loop in the Interface class looks suspicious

Comment: You're also making the frame visible before you're finished updating the UI, also the null layout is doing you no favours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while(true)`condition will get you Out of Memory at some point.
Remove it and your frame should be rendered asuming all variables are correctly initialized. (You can do the server polling in the separate thread)